# How can I write a user defined function in MySQL so that when I delete a row from one table, that particular row from another table also gets deleted?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `student`

(
  `student_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_first_name` varchar(30) not null,
  `student_lase_name` varchar(30) not null,
  `student_roll_no` int(5) not null,
  `student_class` int(2) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `result_sheet_1`
(
  `student_id` int(5),
  `student_first_name` varchar(30),
  `student_lase_name` varchar(30),
  `student_roll_no` int(5),
  `student_class` int(2),
  `mid_1_english` int(2),
  `mid_2_english` int(2),
  `mid_1_mathematics` int(2),
  `mid_2_mathematics` int(2),
  `semester_final_english` int(2),
  `semester_final_mathematics` int(2)
);

delimiter $$
create trigger result_sheet_1_insert_trigger

after insert on student
for each row 
begin 
insert into result_sheet_1(student_id, student_first_name, student_lase_name, student_roll_no, student_class, mid_1_english, mid_2_english, mid_1_mathematics, mid_2_mathematics, semester_final_english, semester_final_mathematics)
values (new.student_id, new.student_first_name, new.student_lase_name, new.student_roll_no, new.student_class, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

end$$
delimiter ;
```

I want to delete a row from result_sheet_1 through a user defined function whenever that particular row gets deleted from student table. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a trigger for it

Comment: Why a user defined function (it's not the way I would do it)? I would have expected a foreign key on student_id in result_sheet with an on delete cascade clause.

Comment: I've used a trigger but it's not working, i can't delete a row if i create a trigger


delimiter $$
create trigger result_sheet_1_delete_trigger

after delete on student
for each row 
begin 
delete from result_sheet_1
where result_sheet_1.student_id = student.student_id;

end$$
delimiter ;

Comment: Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger..In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: P.Salmon 
that on delete cascade clause worked, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Foreign Key to perform the task with using Cascade.

> ALTER TABLE `result_sheet_1` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`)
>   REFERENCES `test`.`student`(`student_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE;

Answer (score 1):

**Direct answer:**

You could use a procedure or even a trigger but not a function.

**Advice:**

If this is just an example and you are not really saving the exact same data in two different tables, use foreign keys. Then you can even add recursive deletes. If this is your actual structure, you should rethink it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger, or a cascade constraint, or you can just write the logic into the DELETE query itself, but there's so much wrong with your schema, that I really think you need to step back and review how relational databases work.

Some points to consider:

- In MySQL, the number in parentheses after the INT is almost meaningless. I would encourage you to omit this value entirely and let MySQL assume the default value for that data type.
- I'm not sure what student_class is, but it might not be sensible to store it in the student table
- Storing any student information other than the student_id in the results table is obviously redundant
- See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet. You wouldn't have a separate column for each subject. Instead (and slightly depending on your enrolment process) your results table might look something like this:

  student_id,
  year,
  term/semester, 
  subject_id,
  score